# socket.on("connection") with local eventEmitter listeners creating too many eventEmitter listeners

Tags: node.js, events, socket.io

I am trying to use `socket.io` alongside a local event listener within the `socket.on("connection", client => {...} )` event. The problem is every time a new `socket.io` connection is created it's creating a new event listener. This eventually leads to a max listeners error in node.js.

I need that event listener there so it can await data from other parts of the application and then use the returned socket.io `client` object to emit that data to the connected socket.io client.

Should I simply increase `setMaxListeners` per the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_setmaxlisteners_n)? Or is there something I should be doing differently with my code to prevent the creation of a new event listener each time the client connects (e.g. is there a way to register the event listener globally, but pass  and use new client connections into the event listener)?

```
io.on('connection', client => {
    //console.log("Websockets client connected")
    
    events.on("initializePage", data => {
        client.emit("initializePage", data)
    })
    client.on('disconnect', () => { 
        console.log("Socket.io client disconnected")    
    })

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the snippet of code you present, the global `events` eventEmitter will have a new listener attached for each new socket. So indeed, after a while the `maxListeners` will be rapidly exhausted if many clients connect.

A first step to avoid adding listeners indefinitely would be to some clean up each time a client disconnects, by tearing down all the listeners it registered with the `off` method.

In the case the clients only need to be notified one time, you can decide to register the listener using the `once` method instead of `on`, which will do the clean up automatically after one trigger.

But, to get back more specifically to `socket.io`, I feel you're in the situation when you want to perform some kind of broadcast/multicast. Therefore, what about using the namespace system and call:

```js
events.on("initializePage", data => {
  io.sockets.emit("initializePage", data);
})
```

This code has to be written at the top level of your file, not in the `connection` handler.

Comment: You are correct, I'm trying to broadcast the page data to any client that connects. I guess it didn't occur to me that I could use the namespace system for this, but it's kind of obvious for bulk operations like I'm doing now that you've pointed it out. Giving this a try...